# How to add the "page" post type to Recent Activity widget displayed in admin?

Tags: widgets, admin, dashboard

I already know how to custom the default Recent Activity widget displayed in Dashboard in order to show the last Custom Post Types published :

```
add_filter( 'dashboard_recent_posts_query_args', function(array $queryArgs) {
    $postTypes = get_post_types([
        'public'          => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    ]);

    if ( is_array( $postTypes ) ) {
        $queryArgs['post_type'] = $postTypes;
    }

    return $queryArgs;
}, 15 );
```

So, now, the widget is displaying the last post and last custom post published. But what about the pages ?

**How to add the pages** to this widget ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `page` post type to your code (tested):

```php
add_filter( 'dashboard_recent_posts_query_args', function(array $queryArgs) {
    $postTypes = get_post_types([
        'public'          => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    ]);

   $postTypes[] = 'page';

    if ( is_array( $postTypes ) ) {
        $queryArgs['post_type'] = $postTypes;
    }

    return $queryArgs;
}, 15 );
```

The reason your original code did not include pages is because pages have their own separate capability type: `edit_page` instead of `edit_post`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have been trying different solutions all day long ! May I ask where you found that pages had the edit_page capability type ?

Comment: It’s hard to say, as I’ve known for a long time. The documentation for the function that creates the built-in post types shows that `page` is registered with a different capability type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/create_initial_post_types/.